# Homomorphisms of vectorial spaces, off by a constant

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Knowing that for every vector $v$ , $g(v)=c\cdot f(v)$, with $c$ depending on to which vector is applied $g$ , I have to prove that $g = c \cdot f$ for one unique constant $c$.

I don't know from where to start solving this problem. Some tips would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are $f$ and $g$?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try being more specific. I guess that $f$ and $g$ are linear maps $V\to W$, where $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and the assumption is that, for every $v\in V$, there exists a scalar $c_v$ such that $g(v)=c_vf(v)$.

Your task is to prove that there exists a scalar $c$ such that $g(v)=cf(v)$, for every $v\in V$.

A hint to start: suppose $f(v_1)$ and $f(v_2)$ are linearly independent; we can write
\begin{align}
& g(v_1)=c_{v_1}f(v_1)=pf(v_1) \\
& g(v_2)=c_{v_2}f(v_2)=qf(v_2) \\
& g(v_1+v_2)=c_{v_1+v_2}f(v_1+v_2)=rf(v_1+v_2)
\end{align}
(using $p,q,r$ for simplicity). We have, by linearity,
$$
pf(v_1)+qf(v_2)=rf(v_1)+rf(v_2)
$$
which implies $p=q=r$.

Now the idea is to generalize this by considering $\{f(v_1),\dots,f(v_n)\}$ a basis for the image of $f$.

Comment: Thank you very much , I have understood the idea .